# Крякозябры в выводе из БД mysql + python

Tags: python, mysql

Как это исправить?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-

import MySQLdb

try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="censore", passwd="censore", db="censore", charset='utf8', use_unicode = True)
except MySQLdb.Error as err:
    print("Connection error: {}".format(err))
    conn.close()

sql = "SELECT title, kp_id_movie FROM post WHERE id = 912"

try:
    cur = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()
except MySQLdb.Error as err:
    print("Query error: {}".format(err))

print(data[92])
conn.close()
```

Даже encode/decode не помогли. Версия python и ее пакеты свежие.

Запуск

> python mysql.py

Вывод

> ({'kp_id_movie': 696499L, 'title': u'\u0413\u0430\u043b\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u043d (2018)'},)

В PHP корректно выводит.

```
array(2) { ["kp_id_movie"]=> string(6) "696499" ["title"]=> string(25) "Галвестон (2018)" }
```

Comment: Абсолютно нормальный вывод. Это не крякозябры, это юникодная строка с русскими символами в питоновом формате с экранированием неанглийских симолов

Comment: Давайте с другой стороны: чем вам помешал этот вывод? Есть какие-то иные проблемы, помимо чисто эстетических «ужас-ужас русские символы экранировались принтом»?

Comment: @andreymal после записи в блокнот лежат строки из БД, там тоже крякозябры, так должно быть? Или как можно enкодировать?

Comment: А как вы записываете?